# How to fix "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for npm-update?

Tags: npm-update

I'm currently having issues with some of my modules being outdated/missing for my Discord.js bot, so I want to use npm-update to fix my outdated/missing packages. When I go to use the command; I get a syntax error in the PowerShell window.

I've already tried updating npm and reinstalling it, no difference was made. Same error.

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\zombi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\zombi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\zombi\Documents\code projects\Discord Bots\Duck Bot\node_modules\integer
gyp ERR! node -v v8.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js-commando@0.10.0 requires a peer of sqlite@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enmap@4.3.3 requires a peer of better-sqlite-pool@^0.1.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN duck_bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@1.0.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@1.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zombi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-26T13_12_30_616Z-debug.log
```

I expect npm to update all the packages/reinstall missing modules that the bot relies on, but I only get an error.